# Not able to make any changes with dock in Ubuntu 18.04.03

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

After updating my dock back to default position and now I am not able to make any changes with the desktop setting, dock setting, not able to make a new profile with the terminal.

Comment: Be ore specific: 1) describe how you previously changed settings and uptated back to default 2) describe how you are now trying to change settings and what not works.

Comment: go to setting > dock
Choose the bottom option from "Position on screen"
It go back to left, Not able to save my changes

Comment: Edit your answer to add all relevant information.